# What would be the most suitable phrase or idiom for a situation where I am very bad at one thing and extremely good at a different related thing?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

E.g.

I am extremely bad at playing football but extremely good at playing foosball.

So what would be the appropriate phrase or idiom for such a scenario?

Comment: Football-Foosball?

Comment: @Dim Foosball is another name for table football - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_football. As for the question: see this previous thread: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/382318/what-is-the-single-word-for-someone-who-is-exceptional-at-one-thing-but-horribl

Comment: Haha, football and foosball are related like football and a FIFA video game. I get your point, I just found it funny.

Comment: Uh… even if football and foosball were somehow related, there would still be no word or phrase in English for what you seem to be trying to describe.

To make it clear to all replace the "foosball" with "cricket" and then ask again…

Answer (score 1):

*My football and foosball skills are chalk and cheese.*.

> https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/chalk-and-cheese.html.
>   We have hundreds of phrases to indicate the similarity of one thing with another and similes like 'as alike as two peas in a pod' are commonplace in everyday speech. There are far fewer expressions that explicitly refer to the difference between things; 'as different as chalk and cheese' is the most commonly used. This is an old expression and the earliest citation is in John Gower's Middle English text Confessio Amantis, 1390: *Lo, how they feignen chalk for chese.*